# How to start check during long operation (load data from network)

Tags: android, android-espresso, ui-testing, mockwebserver

Adnroid studio 3.3.

In my app I use Retrofit to do http request.
Also I use MockWebServer to return stub response.

On activity when I click button I start **async** http request (by Retrofit) and wait callback method to return response. Here Espresso's test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class AddTraderActivityTest {
@get:Rule
    var addTraderIntentTestRule: IntentsTestRule<AddTraderActivity> = IntentsTestRule(AddTraderActivity::class.java)

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        mockServer = MockWebServer()
        mockServer.start(8081)
        Debug.d(TAG, "SUCCCESS_START_MOCKWEBSRVER")
    }

  @Test
fun buttonStart_click_longResponse() {
    // stub response
    mockServer.enqueue(MockResponse()
            .setResponseCode(200)
            .setBody(FileUtil.getStringFromFile(context, "add_trader_success_200.json"))
            .setBodyDelay(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))

    onView(withId(R.id.baseTextInputEditText))
            .perform(typeText(BASE_TEST))
    onView(withId(R.id.quoteTextInputEditText))
            .perform(typeText(QUOTE_TEST))
    onView(withId(R.id.startButton))
            .perform(click())
    onView(withText(R.id.containerProgressBarLayout))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
}
```

But problem is when execute `perform(click()` the method `check` is not call until not get stub response (after 5 seconds).

But I need call method `check` **immediately** after `perform(click()` method. Because I need to `check` is `containerProgressBarLayout` is `isDisplayed()` while not return stub response.  I need to check my view **DURING** loading data

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Espresso idling resources](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/idling-resource).

> An idling resource represents an asynchronous operation whose results
>   affect subsequent operations in a UI test. By registering idling
>   resources with Espresso, you can validate these asynchronous
>   operations more reliably when testing your app.

Also, there is a library for Okhttp, you can check it out [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/okhttp-idling-resource)

Comment: I need to check my view DURING loading data. Not after data was loaded. Is it possible by Espresso idling resources?

Comment: @Alexei, I don't know how you implement your mock server, it depends. But try to create an idling resource and always return true inside `isIdleNow` so It maybe skips waiting and goes to the next step.

Comment: I use this mockwebserver https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver

Comment: isIdleNow = true is not help. Method "onView(withId(R.id.startButton)).perform(click())" "freeze" application. And method "check" call AFTER 5 seconds.